# Android espresso test setPortraitOrientation stuck

Tags: testing, android-activity, android-espresso

I am testing some scenarios where I rotate the screen to Landscape mode and then brings back to Portrait mode but in my tests once I turn the screen to Landscape it never turn back to Portrait and the test framework is stuck and never fails. Seems like there is some activity going on. Used mainActivity in the test setup

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do use the same call you are doing in some of my tests, and all works fine. 
Is your activity being destroyed and recreated when you go to landscape? If yes, maybe there is some processing happening on destroy/creation that is stuck.
There is a slight different thing I do, that maybe you can check. If the activity is destroyed when you turn it to landscape, maybe the second call happens for an activity object that is ready to be destroyed, and hence does not resume again. You can try to call getActivity() before going back to portrait again. What I do is to always rotate the current resumed activity, using a function like described here: http://qathread.blogspot.com.br/2014_09_01_archive.html